# ImportError after importing matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, importerror

please could any one help!
Trying to `import matplotlib` I get this `ImportError: *cannot import name 'artist' from 'matplotlib'*.`
I removed the package `(*py -m pip uninstall matplotlib*)` and reinstall it but I still get the same error.
Thanks!

Comment: What is your import command?

Comment: which version of `matplotlib` are you using? type `pip list| grep matplotlib
`

Comment: import command: py -m pip install matplotlib

Comment: This is how you install it. How do you import the package in your code?

Comment: sorry, import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Comment: matplotlib version 3.5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the common reasons why Python packages cannot be imported is because of its virtual environments. Basically when you install a package manager, it creates some root environment for you and you by default install all packages there. Now this issue may arise if you download a package into another VE, then in your code editor you should pick the one where it lies. I recommend you to check if your package is installed and pick that environment in the IDE, however from what I know it generates a different error message, something like the import couldn't be resolved. Did it help you?

Comment: Thanks, but how can I pick that environment in the IDE? Sorry I'm a beginner.

Comment: I'm working with jupyter notebook

Comment: What IDE exactly do you use? VSCode, PyCharm, Vim, something else?

Comment: As IDE I use VSCode